# Any Java ORM for dynamically created database tables?

Tags: java, orm

We are thinking about switching from our custom made code to an ORM, in order to simplify our code base and move to a possibly more robust code. Currently we have a few "system" tables and a variable number of "custom" tables. Those custom tables are different for each installation: a customer may have tables about invoices, anther may have tables about insurance policies, and so on. These custom tables may be added any time and should be immediately available to the users. We wrote a bunch of java classes following the DBO schema: a class for each system table, plus one generic class for the custom tables. And, we have a generic java object that instantiate the custom records; this class have generic methods like `Object getProperty(String name)`.

We had a look at a few ORMs, but we could not find any that will simplify the use of such custom tables.

Is there anyone with similar experience? Thanks.

Comment: All the Java ORMs I know of assume that the tables that they map to objects exist. If they don't, they will throw an exception when querying them. You might deal with these exceptions, or you could create all the tables always, and leave them empty if they aren't used.

Comment: @JBNizet, there are not predefined "custom" tables: every customer may design its own tables.

Comment: Then an ORM is not the solution. (But I don't see how anything can be a solution). How can you handle tables that you know nothing about?

Comment: I know everything about that table, but only at runtime. When program is written I do not have any idea about these tables, but every time a user defines ones, I do have all details (name, fields type, primary key, foreign keys, default values). I wonder if it would be possible to create also a java class (using the reflection java API) and satisfy ORM requirements?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you do when a customer creates a new table in its database, with a name, a set of columns and types that you never heard of before? How can your existing code magically handle it and implement new functional use-cases based on this new table, without changing anything to the code?

Comment: Program is a DMS, so we basically store and retrieve documents. Every document has a few properties, so we create a table for all document kinds. Once created, user may insert/search/delete/update for that document. Every user action is translated in SQL. The GUI is completely dynamic and design itself based on the document itself. Column types may only be string/numeric/date and other simple ones.

Comment: OK. Now I start to understand. Then I don't know of any ORM that will handle such a case. In a normalized database schema, that an ORM could use, you would store all the documents in a single table, containing a "kind" column. I'm not saying that you should do that. Maybe you have very good reasons to have the database designed as it is. But an ORM (or at least, JPA-based ones) can't handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a task for a query mapper framework better than an ORM.

For example, using [MyBatis](http://mybatis.github.com/mybatis-3/) you can dynamically map even the table name (See [Setting the FROM clause via parameter in MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350220/setting-the-from-clause-via-parameter-in-mybatis))

```
<select id="getLookupRows" parameterType="map" resultMap="lookupMap">
   select id, name, active, valid
   from ${table}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [orm](/questions/tagged/orm), you should really focus on having a complete and mature object model. Having that done, mapping the objects to the relational database follows naturally. As the comment by '@JB Nizet' says, you need to have all your objects. So, perhaps it might be useful to reconsider your design and adapt it to work with an [orm](/questions/tagged/orm), be it [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) or any other.

[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) has an experimental feature called ['Dynamic models'](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels), I don't know a great deal about it, since I haven't had the chance to use it, but I guess it might give you some insights. Also note that it is an experimental feature at the moment and hence, might change in the future.

Comment: I just read about dynamic models, but they still require a specific Java class that must correspond to a table, and I think you have to read the XML configuration file at startup, when creating the factory. I don't know if you may destroy a factory and create a new one every time a "custom" table is created or altered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into ActiveJDBC. It follows dynamic mapping of model attributes to table columns. Check out the docs here http://javalite.io/setters_and_getters and here http://javalite.io/runtime_discovery.